# Running zsh gives compinit:480: compdump: function definition file not found

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have got the above error `compinit:480: compdump: function definition file not found` when I run `zsh` command, I don't have FPATH exported in my `.zshrc` and have tried to reboot the computer and it didn't work. I have tried to brew install something and it gives me the error after I have done it. May I know how to resolve it.
The `echo $FPATH` gives me

```
/Users/tdu1/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git:/Users/tdu1/.oh-my-zsh/functions:/Users/tdu1/.oh-my-zsh/completions:/Users/tdu1/.oh-my-zsh/cache/completions
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you get a solution to this?